# rmw implementation error running ros2 examples

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run the basic rclcpp examples from the colcon tutorial https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/

after installing ROS2 Crystal Clemmys regarding to this instructions https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Linux-Install-Debians/ on my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

running the subscriber example

```
ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber subscriber_member_function
```

i end up in an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to initialized rcl init options: failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/crystal/lib/librmw_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN8eprosima8fastrtps27DataRepresentationQosPolicyE, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-crystal-rmw-implementation-0.6.1/src/functions.cpp:136, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-crystal-rcl-0.6.5/src/rcl/init_options.c:55
```

any hints on how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323756/rmw-implementation-error-running-ros2-examples/) by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2019-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pantphotiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/39777/pantphotiou/) on 2019-05-23**:
same thing happening to me too today. I left some terminals open from yesterday and running things there was ok. as soon as i sourced a new environment i got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem but on Windows after installing Ros2 from binaries.
Building ROS2 from source solved the problem for me.

Other solution I saw was to install OpenSplice and set the rmw implemenation to that.\

---

Originally posted by [PratNag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28957/pratnag/) with karma: 61 on 2019-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0